# How do I add a URL to a notification when using the notification API?

Tags: javascript, api, notifications

I have created a simple notification in a standard index.html file by adding the following script to the bottom of the page. However, my goal is to add a URL to the notification, so that when the user clicks on the notification they are taken to a specific URL (**window.open**). I know this can be done as when searching for an answer on Google many sites have notifications that when clicked navigate to a different page or website. Nevertheless, I have not found a solution that I can get working. Any help welcome.

```
    Notification.requestPermission();
Notification.requestPermission((permission) => {
  switch (permission) {
    case 'granted': {
      console.log('Now we can send notifications!');
      doNotify();
      break;
    }
    case 'denied': {
      console.log('User close the request pop-up!')
    }
  }
});

function doNotify(){
        const title = "Test notification";
        const img = "https://via.placeholder.com/600x400";
        const text = Lorem ipsum;

        const options = {
            body: text,
            icon: "https://via.placeholder.com/600x400",
            data: {
            },
            vibrate: [200, 100, 200],
            tag: "new-product",
            image: img,
            badge: "https://via.placeholder.com/128x128",
        };

        notification.onclick = function(event) {
          event.preventDefault(); // prevent the browser from focusing the Notification's tab
          window.open('http://www.mozilla.org', '_blank');
        }

      navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(function(serviceWorker) {
        serviceWorker.showNotification(title, options);
      });

    // setTimeout( n.close.bind(n), 9000); //close notification after 3 seconds
}
```

Comment: Your current code will throw a couple of errors not related to your original problems. Make sure to fix those in your code.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier Thanks for the insight. The only error reported in my chrome console is one relating to the notification (not defined). No idea how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed a line that is very important for this to work. Define a notification with the `Notification` constructor in which you enter the `title` and `options` variables.

```
function doNotify() {

  const title = "Test notification";
  const img = "https://via.placeholder.com/600x400";
  const text = "Lorem ipsum";

  const options = {
    body: text,
    icon: "https://via.placeholder.com/600x400",
    data: {},
    vibrate: [200, 100, 200],
    tag: "new-product",
    image: img,
    badge: "https://via.placeholder.com/128x128",
  };

  // Add this line.
  const notification = new Notification(title, options);

  notification.onclick = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // prevent the browser from focusing the Notification's tab
    window.open('http://www.mozilla.org', '_blank');
  }

  navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(function(serviceWorker) {
    serviceWorker.showNotification(title, options);
  });

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. I can see how a new const has been declared. I guess this is something I missed off or was not included in the code snippets I used to form my code. Looking at this variable, it appears this line is needed for all notifications like this. Which is why when it was missing, you reported there being an error, not relating to the original request for help etc. Thanks once again and your answer has helped me understand a little bit more :)